# Redirecting users who have come from the wrong Referer

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, http, redirect

Ignoring the merits of whether we should make this change or not (the circumstances are slightly complex and probably covered by my NDA), our client would like us to require that visitors to the site we're building have come from another of their sites. If a user comes to us from elsewhere, they should be sent to the login screen of that other site.

It feels like the easiest way to do this is using `mod_rewrite` to redirect anything with a referrer that is neither our site nor this other one.

My current thinking is

In `httpd.conf`

```
RewriteMap deflector txt:/path/to/deflector.map
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""
RewriteCond ${deflector:%{HTTP_REFERER}|NOT-FOUND} =NOT-FOUND
RewriteRule ^ http://www.theothersite.com/login.jsp [R=307,L]
```

In `deflector.map`

```
//www.oursite.com/ -
//oursite.com/ -
//www.theothersite.com/ -
//theothersite.com/ -
```

This would allow us to expand the list of "permissible referrers" quite easily, which feels like a good idea.

I have three questions then:

1. Is `mod_rewrite` (which we're already using extensively) the best way of doing this?
2. If it is, then is a `307 Temporary Redirect` response the best way to handle it?
3. As I'm not primarily a LAMP dev / admin, have I made any stupid typos in those rewrite rules?  ;o)

It feels to me that `307 Temporary Redirect` or `403 Forbidden` are the most appropriate [status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) and I assume it's A Bad Thing™ to send a `Location:` redirect header with a `4xx` response.

That all make sense?

**Edit:** Are the map searches case-*in*sensitive by default? Do I need to worry about case here?
**Edit 2:** Are map searches a regex search or a whole-key match? If the map contains `www.foo.com` and the `Referer:` header reads `http://www.foo.com/bar.php` will it match?

Comment: Think about what's going to happen here when a browser doesn't return a referer. BTW you can't send a location response with a 4xx status code.

Comment: @symcbean Yeah, that's why I have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !=""` there first. And thanks, I didn't think I could send a `Location:` header with a `4xx` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we've actually ended up doing is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !A.B.C.(D|E)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}==%{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*?)==https?://\1/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !https?://referring.domain.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://referring.domain.com/path/to/login/script [R,L]
```

The first `RewriteCond` (and several more lines like it) mean that developers and the client are not restricted by this referrer check (as it's really tiresome to have to go there first before going to our site).

The second `RewriteCond` is a work of genius to check if the referrer is the same as the `Host:` in the request. This is based on [terrye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142045/terrye)'s [answer to SO#7398191: Generic mod_rewrite referrer check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8828534/205245) — because `mod_rewrite` only does variable interpolation in the test string, you can't have a line reading

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^https?://%{HTTP_REFERER}/ [NC]
```

as it simply won't do that check.

Apparently we're "never" gonna need to allow any other referrers. If we did, I guess I'd just have to set that last `RewriteCond` line to end `[NC,OR]` and chain some more conditions along.

All working nicely. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I think the map will be case-sensitive, and also you need to extract the hostname from the `Referer`. I haven't tested it at all but something like this might perhaps work:

```
RewriteMap deflector txt:/path/to/deflector.map
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^:/?]+)
RewriteCond ${lc:%1} (.+)
RewriteCond ${deflector:%1|NOT-FOUND} =NOT-FOUND
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [L]
```

Don't faff around with unusual response codes; the default of 302 is fine.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thank you. The only thing I'm not sure about is the arguments to the last line — should that `[L]` be `[R,L]` (with `R=302` being implicit)?

Comment: I think the [R] isn't necessary as the rewrite is to an absolute URL so mod_rewrite defaults to it.